# Connection refused quando faço curl para um serviço

Tags: libcurl, xampp, cpanel

Eu tenho um serviço/API que correr no xampp, o xampp está instalado num servidor Windows. A partir do momento, que comecei a ouvir a porta 1500 invés da 80 no xampp, comecei a ter alguns problemas.

Existem 2 situações relevantes para analise.

1. Quando chamo o serviço, via site alojado no CPANEL. Recebo connection refused.
2. Quando uso o mesmo código da chamada, num computador pessoal. Recebo os dados pretendidos no cURL, consigo a conexão e tudo está bem.

Passo a mostrar o código utilizado:

```
    // where are we posting to?
    $url = 'http://dns_para_minha_API_alojada_servidor_windows_correndo_xampp_apache_http_server:1500/ncsync/Sync/getDossierProdutos?ndos=' . $ndos . '&nReg=' . $nReg;

    // open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,    1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    // execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    // close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
```

Tanto no CPANEL, como o servidor, e no computador pessoal, tenho o cURL instalado(confirmação através da instrução phpinfo()).
`Nota: cURL executados no CPANEL, para outas APIs, como a da "google" funcionam.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso provavelmente pode ser um bloqueio do firewall, impedindo que utilize a porta `1500`.

O CPanel vem com um monte de recursos, um deles é o firewall, você pode ver como abrir as portas [na documentação do próprio CPanel](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Configure+Your+Firewall+for+cPanel+Services):

Você deve autorizar o IP/Porta no CSF (Home >> Plugins >> ConfigServer & Firewall) e no `iptables` (execute um `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1500 -j ACCEPT`).

Se este servidor é compartilhado, talvez consulte o administrador/provedor para fazer isso.